# How do I stop SimpleButtons from flickering on mouseDown?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've created a button in Flash Pro with different up, over, down and hitTest states. When I move the mouse over it, it switches from up to over. When I press the mouse down, it briefly goes from over to up again for a single frame, then switches to the down state. I'm not sure if this is considered a bug, but I think it's been happening since AS3 was released. [This is the only thread](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?342796-Button-Flicker-on-MouseDown) I can find on the subject.

Since it's been a few years and it's still happening, does anyone have any new advice on how to stop AS3 SimpleButtons from flickering (showing the up state) on mouseDown?

Failing that, if the only way is to roll my own button, does anyone have an example of a homegrown button class that supports a custom hitTest shape?

Answer (score 0):

My hacktastic workaround is to keep using SimpleButton but override the state changes. I set upState, overState and downState to the same container sprite, then listen for mouse up/over/down/out and insert the display object I want into that container at the right time. It doesn't feel like a solid solution but it works for my purposes.

My simplified code:

```
public class ButtonController 
{
    protected var button:SimpleButton;
    protected var container:Sprite;
    protected var upState:DisplayObject;
    protected var overState:DisplayObject;
    protected var downState:DisplayObject;

    public function ButtonController(button:SimpleButton) {
        this.button = button;
        upState = button.upState;
        overState = button.overState;
        downState = button.downState;

        container = new Sprite();
        button.upState = container;
        button.overState = container;
        button.downState = container;
        container.addChild(upState);

        button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);
        button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);
        button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mouseOver);
        button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, mouseOut);
    }

    protected function mouseDown(...ig):void {
        container.removeChildAt(0);
        container.addChild(downState);
    }

    protected function mouseUp(...ig):void {
        container.removeChildAt(0);
        container.addChild(overState);
    }

    protected function mouseOver(...ig):void {
        container.removeChildAt(0);
        container.addChild(overState);
    }

    protected function mouseOut(...ig):void {
        container.removeChildAt(0);
        container.addChild(upState);
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach adds a slight delay before the mouseover visuals appear. In a traditional SimpleButton, the mouseover state changes then waits one frame before firing the mouseover event. So now the state change is happening one frame later.